# Reading 32 Bytes of file at a time

Tags: python, fat

Working on reading and interpreting FAT12 directory entries. I am trying to determine how to read 32 bytes of the file at a time. So far I have the following:

```
f_name = sys.argv[1] #set file name as the argument to be passed in command line

with open(f_name, mode='rb') as file:
    data = file.read()

struct.unpack(,data[:])
```

Most of the things I have seen say to use struct.unpack() I have looked at the documentation on this and I am having trouble understanding how to use it. Is there an easier way to read 32 bytes at a time until I have read a full 512 bytes?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Answer (score 1):

`file.read()` takes the upper limit of bytes/characters to read and advance the read pointer by:

```
data = file.read(32)
```